# Unable to parse this json file in golang

Tags: json, go

I am trying to write go code to parse the following of json file:

```
{
    "peers": [
        {
            "pid": 1,
            "address": "127.0.0.1:17001"
        },
        {
            "pid": 2,
            "address": "127.0.0.1:17002"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I could do so far is write this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Config struct{
    Pid int
    Address string
}

func main(){
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.json")
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Print("Error:",err)
    }
    var conf Config
    err=json.Unmarshal(content, &conf)
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Print("Error:",err)
    }
    fmt.Println(conf)
}
```

Above code works for non-nested json files like following one:

```
{
    "pid": 1,
    "address": "127.0.0.1:17001"
}
```

But even after changing the `Config struct` so many times. I am not able to parse the json file mentioned at the start of the question. Can somebody please tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following struct definition to map your JSON structure:

```
type Peer struct{
    Pid int
    Address string
}

type Config struct{
    Peers []Peer
}
```

[Example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/6gIwM0tYI8).

Answer (score 0):

To include custom attribute names, add struct field tags as:

```
type Peer struct{
        CustomId int `json:"pid"` 
        CustomAddress string `json:"address"`
    }
```